# Customizing Azure Active Directory unauthorized error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Enterprise Application registered on Azure Active Directory and I want only certain AAD users to be able to access it. I have created a user group for the authorized users and everything works fine. The users who are not assigned to the application, as expected, can't sign-in and they get an error message like the following after successful authentication. Is it possible to customize this message? I just need to add a support email address.

[image: unauthorised user message]

Comment: customization of error message in AAD may not be possible as in AADB2C. You may try to give the support email in "sign-in page text and formatting" entry box by adding [Company branding page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding#to-customize-your-branding) for AAD sign-in .But this appears in sign in page with or without login failure. (But it requires azure ad Premium 1, Premium 2, or Office 365 (for Office 365 apps) licenses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customization of error message in AzureAD may not be possible as in AADB2C. You may try to give the support email in "`sign-in page text and formatting`" entry box through  [Company branding page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/customize-branding#to-customize-your-branding) for AAD sign-in .But this page appears as background in sign in page no matter success or failure of user authentication.

[image]

> **Note** :Company branding  requires azure ad Premium 1, Premium 2, or
> Office 365 (for Office 365 apps) licenses.